# How to trick Uploadify into thinking all files are the same size?

Tags: jquery, uploadify

Is there a way to trick Uplodify into thinking all files are the same size? I'm not using it to upload files, but rather to gather filenames in a text file. Therefore, I don't want the user to think the files are actually being uploaded. I have it to the point where the progress bar zips through. But you still have to wait for the next item to start "processing."

I have all the Uploadify source files. I'm assuming it's something in one of the .as files since I've tried altering pretty much everything in the .fla file to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Got some help with this one on another forum and I thought I would share. Here's the Uploadify script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
('#file_upload').uploadify({
  'uploader'    : 'uploadify.swf',
  'script'      : 'uploadify.php',
  'cancelImg'   : 'cancel.png',
  'folder'      : '/uploads',
  'multi'       : true,
  'onProgress' : function(event,ID,fileObj) {
$('#file_upload').uploadifyCancel($('.uploadifyQueueItem').first().attr('id').replace('file_upload',''))
  }
});
});
</script>
```

What happens is after the PHP functions in the uploadify.php file are complete, Uploadify's onProgress starts. When there is a change in the progress (which is almost immmediately), the item is removed from the queue.

Hope this helps someone someday.